# React 18 MSW Codesandbox

Tags: reactjs, codesandbox, msw

I have my own sandbox template that I am trying to upgrade to react 18 but getting errors about an music directive location is undefined. Not sure what is missing

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-w-mswjs-tailwindcss-wermmh

Is it something with my typescript setup that is causing the issue?